# Read XML ( Map/TileSet data ) and draw it to panel - C#

Tags: c#, xml, tiles

I'm trying to make a simple tile based game engine in C#, just for fun.

When I'm simply load an image and draw it all over the panel inside 2 for loops, it works fine. Now I'm decided to make a Map class to handle XML maps, but it's not working as I expected.

I think, the problem is in the XML reader part, but I don't know what's that.

As you can see on the below image, the default "noimage" was displaying on the panel. However, it needs to display the map using the informations from the xml files.
(Load the image, cut it into tiles, then draw it to the panel inside the for loops).

The main code inside Form1:

```
Map testmap = new Map("test.xml");

for (int y = 0; y < testmap.Height; y += 1)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < testmap.Width; x += 1)
    {
        int t = int.Parse(testmap.Data[y].Substring(x, 1));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(testmap.TileSet, new Rectangle(x*32, y*32, 32, 32), testmap.Tiles[t], GraphicsUnit.Pixel); 
    }
}
```

Map.cs:

```
class Map
{
    public string File = "";
    public int Width = 0;
    public int Height = 0;

    public List<string> Data = new List<string>();

    public Image TileSet = Image.FromFile("data/tiles/default.png");
    public List<Rectangle> Tiles = new List<Rectangle>();

    public Map(string fname)
    {
        File = fname;
        XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader("data/maps/" + File);
        while (xml.Read())
        {
            if (xml.Name == "tileset")
            {
                XmlTextReader xml2 = new XmlTextReader("data/tiles/" + xml.Value);
                while (xml2.Read())
                {
                    if (xml2.Name == "image")
                    {
                        TileSet = Image.FromFile("data/tiles/" + xml2.Value);
                    }
                    else if (xml2.Name == "tile")
                    {
                        xml2.MoveToAttribute("x");
                        int x = int.Parse(xml2.Value);
                        xml2.MoveToAttribute("y");
                        int y = int.Parse(xml2.Value);

                        Tiles.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (xml.Name == "w")
            {
                Width = int.Parse(xml.Value);
            }
            else if (xml.Name == "h")
            {
                Height = int.Parse(xml.Value);
            }
            else if (xml.Name == "row")
            {
                Data.Add(xml.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

data/maps/map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Test Map -->
<tileset>grass.xml</tileset>
<w>16</w>
<h>16</h>
<map>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
</map>
```

data/tiles/grass.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Grass TileSet -->
<image>grass.png</image>
<tileset>
    <tile x="16" y="48"></tile>
    <tile x="0" y="0"></tile>
</tileset>
```

[image: The problem]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: As you can see on the image, the default "noimage" was displaying on the panel. However, it needs to display the map using the informations from the xml files.

Comment: `I'm trying to make a simple tile based game` - winforms is not a suitable platform for games (nor for anything else I can think of). For simple stuff, use WPF. For serious game programming, look into Unity, or straight hardcore C++ DirectX.

Comment: I know that it's not the best framework for games, but it can be done. There is many ways to create games (XNA, Game Maker, etc..), but I want to complete it in C# WinForms, because I like it, and want to learn somwthing new.

Comment: Don't mind HighCore, he hates winforms. Yes he is right, but you are learning here.

Comment: your, `data/maps/map.xml` is not valid XML

Comment: @NicolasTyler what's the problem, and how can I make it valid?

Comment: @BalázsVarga - `"I want to learn something new"` - then learn something `new`. winforms is a really old technology that's not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: Thanks for your very very helpful comments... I meant "something new in C#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iv basically changed the whole system around. iv managed to draw the map to a windows form.

Here is how your Map class should look:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Map
{
    private string[] tilesetField;
    private byte widthField;
    private byte heightField;
    private string[] dataField;

    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("tile", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] tileset
    {
        get
        {
            return tilesetField;
        }
        set
        {
            tilesetField = value;
        }
    }

    public byte width
    {
        get
        {
            return widthField;
        }
        set
        {
            widthField = value;
        }
    }

    public byte height
    {
        get
        {
            return heightField;
        }
        set
        {
            heightField = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("row", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] data
    {
        get
        {
            return dataField;
        }
        set
        {
            dataField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how your XML should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Map>
  <tileset>
    <tile>grass.png</tile>
    <tile>grass1.png</tile>
  </tileset>
  <width>16</width>
  <height>16</height>
  <data>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
    <row>0001000000001000</row>
    <row>0000000110000000</row>
    <row>0000000000000000</row>
  </data>
</Map>
```

Now you can simply draw the map like this:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Map));
    Map testmap;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
    {
        testmap = (Map)ser.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < testmap.height; y += 1)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < testmap.width; x += 1)
        {
            int t = int.Parse(testmap.data[y].Substring(x, 1));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(testmap.tileset[t]), new Rectangle(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32));
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the XML can explain exactly how it works,
Firstly, like your first design the map had a width and height. The map also has tiles, these tiles are listed in the tileset. The order they are in is the index of the tile.
Then the data of the map is rows and columns of tile indexes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try, then come back to leave a feedback! :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use that? I can't access any variables inside this class, and I don't know how the XML variables are stored. I've simply replaced my code with yours, but there is no any change...

Comment: Hi, i have changed everything. its now much simpler and it draws to the form.